# How to check if an array that has objects in react components state has duplicate values before sending a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I have a state:

```
 const [persons, setPersons] = useState([{ id: 1, name: "Arto Hellas" }]);
 const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");
```

A simple form:

```
 <form onSubmit={addName}>
    <div>
      name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And the handlers for the form. I can add new names and render them but
Im trying to check if the name typed in the input has allready been added and if so just a simple alert that its not possible. I have banged my head in the wall for hours trying everything I could but with my knowledge it just isnt going anywhere. (Starter exercises for open uni at my country)

Comment: Please also post your `handleNameChange` and `addName` code.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the element in persons, If it is present then `alert`, `console.log`, or tell the user that it is not possible else add into the state.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-voice-y8jnd?file=/src/App.js:215-561)

I've used `console.log`, You can use `alert` or anything to tell the user.

```
function addName(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isPresent = persons.find((p) => p.name === newName);
    if (!isPresent) {
      setPersons((state) => {
        return [...state, { id: state.length + 1, name: newName }];
      });
      setNewName("");    // Clear the input
    } else {
      console.log("Not possible");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Holy macaroni it works! Thank you so much. I had tries close to that but something was missing. Gotta try understand how this works. But cheers !

Comment: @KristianHusso Glad I could help

Comment: try to debug it as much as you can. It will empower your debug skills also and let you learn how the code flows. ☺